# How to add Javascript into a component without disabling other script?

Tags: javascript, components

I use Swatch template by woothemes. I have modified the logo component, and I want to add this following script to my logo. I copied this script in the header.php.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function coba() {
                    // set opacity to nill on page load
                    $("#logo a span").css("opacity","0");
                    // on mouse over
                    $("#logo a span").hover(function () {
                        // animate opacity to full
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 'slow');
                    },
                    // on mouse out
                    function coba() {
                        // animate opacity to nill
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 'slow');
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

but, when I run it, the other script was disabled. All of them, js for slider,prettyphoto,comments,etc. How can I activate all off them at once? Thanks

Comment: have you debugged this? maybe the code is broken, and cuts the javascript execution.
why are you including jquery there? its the only place where its included?

Comment: That's probably due to some javascript error, check your console output.

Comment: I think your code is broken. Not sure why you have 2 function coba, first one should be anonymous as short for $(document).ready() and the second argument of your hover function is a named function again, anonymous will be fine and at least no conflicts guaranteed. and use fadeIn/fadeOut or fadeTo instead of the animate function it's shorter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could have an issue with a recursive call tying up your browser thread ina  busy loop. The following code works but without requiring a recursive call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            // set opacity to nill on page load
            $("#logo a span").css("opacity","0");

            $("#logo a span").hover(
                function () {
                    // on mouse over
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 'slow');
                },
                function () {
                    // on mouse out
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 'slow');
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where should i put it? I tried to add it into header.php, but it didn't work. actually the main problem is when i add "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>" before that, my slider jquery script can't work. in the general.js of my theme, i found this error, "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slides'".. ??

Comment: The `<script>` tags can go anywhere on the page. Are you using Firefox or Chrome to debug your JS? If firefox, install the firebug plug-in. Chrome comes with something similar out of the box. Press F12 to bring up your debugging options. Most likely there are errors reported on the `console` so you can track down the offending lines of code.